# Writing a table for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The table will look like this

```
STUDENTID | FRIEND1 | FRIEND2 | ADDRESS | TUITIONPAID
```

And student ID, Friend 1 and friend 2 will be a combination of four, five or six numbers and characters

TUITION will be a true/false

Of course, STUDENTID should be unique for all rows.

Am I using the right types?

```
STUDENTID - Varchar (6)
Friend1 - Varchar (6)
Friend2 - Varchar (6)
Address - Varchar (255)
TUITION - BIT (3)
```

And should STUDENTID be "unique" or "primary key"?

And lastly, if I am building a table of three million rows, is it recommended to separate into three tables?  Or 1 table is good enough?

Comment: Can a student only have two friends? No. You should therefor have a table for friendship relations. I would recommend `BOOL` for your `tuition` column. But I really don't understand the goal of this table.

Comment: well in real life I guess students would have more friends but in this example, I am just pretending that each student can have upto two friends.  Thanks!!

Comment: Why pretend and design it wrong, when you can just do it right in the first place?

Comment: Well this is the start of bad table design. With an extra table every person can have an arbitrary number of friends, even zero. Do it right, right from the begin.

Comment: Are you pretending that just to fit a notion that it is easier? Why not just model it correctly with STUDENT and FRIENDS table?

Comment: Use integers with `AUTO_INCREMENT` for IDs. You can have a separate `username` column. The ID would be the primary key, and `username` would have a unique index to prevent duplicates.

Comment: Ideally, I would think you want 3 tables - Student (StudentID, AddressID, Tuition) and Friend (FriendID, StudentID, AddressID) and Address (AddressID, Address)

Comment: I thought there was no such data type as BOOLEAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets separate the questions.

> Am I using the right types?

Yes from what I could understand you can use this model you created.

> And should STUDENTID be "unique" or "primary key"?

A primary key is better, but it can also be unique, since you can have a student that came back to study after a long period away.

> And lastly, if I am building a table of three million rows, is it recommended to separate into three tables? Or 1 table is good enough?

Size doesn't matter (much). You can have one table for all the rows.

Obs: If you have a lot of columns, you can think of separating them into more tables. If you have a lot of rows, use only one table.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!  Do you recommend AUTO_INCREMENT?  I plan to store 3 million records, but not any more.

Comment: Yes, using AUTO_INCREMENT will save you time and the need of creating a way to populate the STUDENTID column

Answer (score 1):

You are using the right types except TUITION - BIT (3). 
Since you want it to be true/false **use BOOLEAN**

STUDENTID should definitely be your primary key.

It shouldn't be a problem to use 1 table but you could make more.
For example:

Table 1: STUDENTID 1 - 1,000,000

Table 2: STUDENTID 1,000,001 - 2,000,000

Table 3: STUDENTID 2,000,001 +

I still don't see much point in making more tables though. 3M rows are pretty easy for modern computers.

Comment: I thought boolean was not available for SQL last time I checked?  Or is it?

Comment: Yes, it is. Actually, it is a synonym of TINYINT but in a way that zero values are considered false and non-zero values considered true.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, I would think you want 3 tables -

```
Student - StudentID (primary key), AddressID, TuitionPaid
Friend - (FriendID (primary key), StudentID (foreign key)
Address (AddressID (primary key), Address)
```

But that is assuming that any Friend of a Student is also a Student. Did not specify though.